# Not able to get location using GPS

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

I am developing one app. In which, I need to get the current location of the user. I am getting current location using Network but when I start the GPS its not showing me current location. What coubld be the problem?

```
public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);

        String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        System.out.println("Best Provider:"+bestProvider);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "GPS and Network not enabled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        //LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        bestProvider,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            //.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                            .getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
                    if (location != null) {
                        startLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                        startLongitude = location.getLongitude();

                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            //LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            bestProvider,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                //.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                                .getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}
```

I have added permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: please a bit more precise: Do you see the GPS icon blinking or not in status pane?

Comment: its blinking in status panel.

Comment: when blinking stop then you should receive a GPS fix in onLocationChanged() method. did you implemented this method in your class.

Comment: yup, I implemented LocationListner class.

Comment: Still not clear, does the blinking stops?

Comment: no, its not stopping.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35351/discussion-between-user2439755-and-saurabh)

Answer (score 0):

google has released a nice API on their recent Google IO 2013 event:

https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/324498944

you should check it out and see how you can minimize your code.

do note that it requires that the device would have the play store app for this to work.

this method has many advantages over using the normal location sensors (battery, speed , accuracy,...) .